# How to solve the equation $x^{\log_3{(x-1)}} = 3^{(3+\log_3{x})}$ [SOLVED]

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I made a mistake copying the question ! it should be $x^{\log_3{(x)}-1} = 3^{(3+\log_3{x})}$.

I'm trying to solve the equation:
$x^{\log_3{(x-1)}} = 3^{(3+\log_3{x})}$

What I tried:

I took the logarithm base 3 of both sides which resulted in:
$\log_3{x^{\log_3{(x-1)}}} = 3 + \log_3{x}$

I then used the logarithm property $\log_b(a^c) = c \log_b(a)$ to get:
$\log_3{x} \cdot \log_3{(x-1)} = 3 + \log_3{x}$

I tried to express the right-hand side as a product, realizing that:
$3^{(3+\log_3{x})}$
could be expressed as:
$3^3 \times 3^{\log_3{x}}$
which becomes:
27x

However, I am struggling to find a way to simplify or solve the equation from here.

The asnwers should be 27, $1/3$

Question:
How can I solve this equation either algebraically or using any special methods?

Any guidance or assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The right hand of your original equation is $\;3^3\cdot 3^{\log_3x} = 27x\ldots \;$...and at least $\;x=27\;$ is *not* an answer. Obviously neither is $\;x=\frac13\;$ since then $\;\log_3\;$ would have a negative argument. Check carefully yourquestion.

Comment: @DonAntonio it's according to the textbook .. there's no full solution but there's only asnwers.

Comment: Then your book is wrong ; The definition domain of that equation is $\;x>1\;$ ...so $\;x=\frac13\;$ cannot be an answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio oh maybe ? .. then do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Cannot be solved as you wrote it since that equation cannot be. I'm suspecting that in the left hand if should be $\;x^{\log_3x -1}\;$ ...Check this!

Comment: @DonAntonio wait that's absolutely right! i didn't even notice ,, thank you !!

Comment: Well, now try it again...

Comment: @DonAntonio everything is fine now! i assumed that t = log_3^(x) and x = 3^t ! again thank u for your time!